# 750W PSU enough to handle 2 rx 5700 XT?

Tags: power-supply, dual-gpu

Current system specs:

Asrock 990fx extreme9 FX 6350 24gb ram ASRock 5700 XT challenger Corsair 750W PSU

As shown in the rundown of my current specs I already have a 5700 XT in my system already but I'm thinking of purchasing another to be able to play at high fps in 4k but I'm unsure if the 750W PSU is enough for 2 GPU I recreated my full system in pcpartpicker to get a rough estimate on consumption and it came to be around 711W I understand that at 711W I won't be able to OC I'm just looking for if it will run them at stock during gaming

Comment: It doesn't look like enough of a margin to me ....

Comment: Use pcpartpicker.com, put your current setup in and see what it says about power consumption.

Comment: [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) V[oltage] x A[mperage] = W[attage]: Per the consumption estimate, you do not have enough power for (2x) RX 5700XT, as while AMD does not list their max power usage, they list average power consumption as 225W/per Even with one, 39W is not a lot of leeway (at 12V, it's a spare 3.25A only).

Answer (score -2):

Not enough I say buy psu with 1000W gold or more but why 2 ? for gaming 1 rx 5700xt will be enough I also advice don't buy right now cause amd about to release new cards  . I also advice you not to buy Amd Rdna but if you already bought them then it's k but nvidia is well optimized for gaming with better drivers .